# Can my spouse use her HSA funds to pay for insurance premiums if she lost her job?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hsa, unemployment

My wife was recently laid off and will be joining my health insurance plan that I have through my employer. She's on a visa, so will not be claiming any unemployment benefits. Since my insurance will be more expensive after adding her, she will be paying the difference out-of-pocket every two weeks. Can she use her HSA balance to pay me that money?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - Insurance premiums are not eligible HSA expenses except in certain circumstances (one being receiving unemployment benefits).

From [the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p969):

> **Insurance premiums.**
>
> You can’t treat insurance premiums as qualified medical expenses unless the premiums are for any of the following.
>
> 1. Long-term care insurance.
> 2. Health care continuation coverage (such as coverage under COBRA).
> 3. Health care coverage while receiving unemployment compensation under federal or state law.
> 4. Medicare and other health care coverage if you were 65 or older (other than premiums for a Medicare supplemental policy, such as Medigap).
>
> The premiums for long-term care insurance (item (1)) that you can treat as qualified medical expenses are subject to limits based on age and are adjusted annually. See Limit on long-term care premiums you can deduct in the Instructions for Schedule A (Form 1040).
>
> Items (2) and (3) can be for your spouse or a dependent meeting the requirement for that type of coverage. For item (4), if you, the account beneficiary, aren’t 65 or older, Medicare premiums for coverage of your spouse or a dependent (who is 65 or older) aren’t generally qualified medical expenses.

Comment: Wouldn't our situation qualify under 3. above?

Comment: You stated in your question that she will not receive any unemployment benefits, so no.

Comment: Honestly, I would just pay the premiums out of pocket and save the HSA money for actual medical expenses.